# How to query api tokens for subaccounts using master account credentials?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm using the python Twilio API.

given a subaccount sid, is there a way to get the existing api key for that sub account. using only the master api credentials, not the subaccount credentials.

I've tried to list all the subaccounts and list all api keys but I can't get an api key for a specified sub account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can get the [resources for a subaccount](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/account) by fetching the subaccount itself first and then [fetching the API keys](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/keys#list) for that account.

To do this in Python, it would look like this:

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_TOKEN"
auth_token = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

subaccount = client.api.accounts("SUBACCOUNT_SID")
keys = subaccount.keys.list()
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: thanks, I was confused about the argument to pass to accounts()